# How to code the special symbol representing Siegel upper-half space

Tags: symbols

I want to obtain the following symbol for denoting the Siegel upper-half space. The picture is as follows:

[image]

I have checked the PDF document `The comprehensive LATEX symbol list`, but I could not find out what I want to look for.

I do not know what is the font type of this symbol, I guess it belongs to some German-Goth style. Anyway I am not sure.

Any suggestions are appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: `\mathfrak{H}` and `\mathfrak{I}`? Looks like `euler`, https://i.stack.imgur.com/980yM.jpg

Comment: @Troy Yes, that's it. It requires `\usepackage{amsfonts}` or `\usepackage{amssymb}`.

Comment: @ Troy Thank you very much! That is exactly what I am looking for.